# Unit testing method which is instantiating final unmockable class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, android-sqlite

This is a bit Android specific but it can be applicable to non-Android projects.

I have this class which maps a `FilterEntity` to `ContentValues`. `FilterEntity` is a data structure that I created and control while `ContentValues` is a final class from the Android SDK which will throw a `RuntimeException` if it is not mocked.

```
public class FilterEntityToContentValuesMapper {

    public ContentValues mapOrThrow(FilterEntity filter) {
        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(FilterSchema.COLUMN_ID, filter.id().toString());
        values.put(FilterSchema.COLUMN_NAME, filter.name());
        // and others...

        return values;
    }
}
```

When tested `ContentValues#put` will immediately throw a `RuntimeException` since it is not mocked but the issue is that it can't be mocked for two reasons. First `ContentValues` is final, second it is being instantiated in the method body.

To solve the first issue I made a `ContentValuesWrapper` which provides the exact same functionality as `ContentValues` but delegates everything to a real `ContentValues` object. For the second issue I made a `ContentValuesWrapperFactory` which provides instances of `ContentValuesWrapper`. The end result is like so:

```
public class FilterEntityToContentValuesMapper {

    private final ContentValuesWrapperFactory contentValuesWrapperFactory;

    public FilterEntityToContentValuesMapper(ContentValuesWrapperFactory contentValuesWrapperFactory) {
        this.contentValuesWrapperFactory = contentValuesWrapperFactory;
    }        

        public ContentValues mapOrThrow(FilterEntity filter) {
            final ContentValuesWrapper values = contentValuesWrapperFactory.createContentValuesWrapper();

            values.put(FilterSchema.COLUMN_ID, filter.id().toString());
            values.put(FilterSchema.COLUMN_NAME, filter.name());
            // and others...

            return values;
        }
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to solve this since I am duplicating functionality with `ContentValuesWrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at power mock https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockFinal

Maybe you can use this instead of wrapping your classes

Comment: I do use PowerMock but I am trying to use it as sparingly as possible since it increases unit test time by ~120ms every time I use it. `ContentValues` is very common to use for database transactions therefore I would have to increase the test time of multiple test classes by using PowerMock every time `ContentValues` is used.